# Are “if”,“provided”, and “supposing” interchangeable in such conditional sentences?

Tags: word-choice, conditional-constructions

For example in this sentence:

> And don't worry **if** you've never played the sport. That experience might help, but it's not necessary. As long as you know the rules and can do the job, you can be a referee!

Can "provided" ,or "supposing" also be used to take place of "if"?

Are  “if”,“provided”, and “supposing” interchangeable in such conditional sentences? Are there any rule about using them?

Detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't exactly know why, but I just don't think "And don't worry provided you've never played the sport" is a good sentence.

Comment: Imho, I think it sounds wrong because it's in conflict with common knowledge. And we usually assume a typical context. This might sound better, "And don't worry, provided you know how to play the sport."

Comment: still confusing...

Comment: It has been edited. I think it's on-topic now.

Comment: I think this question is still off-topic: it reflects no additional research, the additional clauses don't illuminate the seemingly random words you've suggested as possible substitutes. The existing answers ignore the fact that _if_ is a conjunction and _supposing_ and _provided_ are verbs. They fulfill different roles and require different syntax.

Answer (score 2):

They are ***entirely*** different!

> And don't worry if you've never played the sport = If you have never played the sport, it's okay. Do not worry about it

Now you want to replace *if* with *provided*

> And don't worry provided you've never played the sport - sounds *off* to me looking at the original sentence and *its purpose*.

*provided* in such context [means](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=provided) *on condition*. I'd be happy if you explain what makes you think them all interchangeable!

> *"I'll go provided that I can wear what I like"* = If you want me to go, I'll wear what I want. Or else, I'm not interested.

Now,

> And don't worry supposing you've never played the sport -again sounds *off* to me looking at the original sentence and *its purpose*.

*supposing* [means a hypothetical thought. On the assumption that](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supposing)...

> supposing I did agree with you

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you know, all three terms can be used to form conditional sentences. They cannot all be simply interchanged, no. Take a look at dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as

It treats all of those terms at least to some extent.